# Least significant bits in function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, compiler-construction, cpu

I am playing around with a programming language implementation, and I'm wondering how (ill) advised it is to press into service the least significant bits of a function pointer to store data.

Are there any major platforms (AMD64/{Windows/Linux/MacOS}, Arm/{iOS,Android}) in which the 2 least significant bits are ever non-zero in function pointers?  That is, is the alignment for the code at least 4 on major platforms?

Comment: This is very bad practice and actually not needed. Why do you need this ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz, to mark whether it is a function pointer, or a pointer to a closure structure.  Perhaps you could create an answer explaining why it is bad practice, keeping in mind that I'm implementing a PL compiler/runtime.

Comment: _"Arm/{iOS,Android})"_ Thumb functions?

Comment: Since you're implementing it, can't you just *make* it all aligned?

Comment: @harold, there are parts of the toolchain that I do not have control over.  The linker, for example.  In this case I also do not have control over the target-specific code-generator.

Comment: @brooks94: it's bad practice because it's non portable. BTW Apple has used some similar stuff some 30 years ago on the first Macintoshes by using the 8 most significant bits of addresses to store information. This was fine on the M68000 processor where physical addresses were limited to 24 bits but was broken on later processors such as the M68020.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Of course it's not portable. Everyone involved is aware of that. It's still useful, if the non-portability is deemed okay or there is a portable alternative. As for your example: Do you know of a similar change in alignment? Reserved bits becoming expanded is common in the history of computing, alignment becoming more lax is much rarer AFAIK.

Answer (score 6):

I can tell you that Apple's 64-bit runtime (both ARM64 and Intel, I think) uses the least significant bits for flags broadly as you propose. In Objective-C everything is an object and, to be compatible with C, pretty much every object lives on the heap and is recorded by its pointer. In 64-bit mode they've allowed very small objects to live on the stack by fitting them into 62 bits and using the low two to indicate that this isn't really a pointer but a literal object. So you can get short strings, object-wrapped 32-bit and below numbers, etc, directly into the 'pointer' and not put anything on the heap.

However Apple does not do this with the 32-bit runtime (event the 'modern' one as on iOS). So it might be worth researching why that is. Admittedly it could just be because of some architectural quirk carried over from the PowerPC.

As has been pointed out to me in the comments (and why this is now tagged as community wiki), the C standard differentiates between the storage of **function** pointers specifically and all other kinds of pointer. So the above comment may or may not be relevant — I nevertheless believe it is because closures are a separate thing again from data and from functions, in compiled languages the code itself usually having been compiled in advance and the closure itself just being the data to fill the gaps. But the point I'm trying to make is that there are shipping, robust systems out there that assume they can reuse the least significant bits of pointers on systems that require alignment.

Comment: Note that OP is talking about *function* pointers, which AFAIK are rather different beasts.

Comment: But this demonstrates that an existing OS does "abuse" pointers, and while such abuse may not currently be used for function pointers, suggests that assuming that they won't in the future is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, but Objective-C is a strict superset of C so a pointer is a pointer is a pointer, including function pointers. Typed pointers are for the benefit of the programmer. Some projects, like QEMU, exploit that fact dynamically to compile code by stringing together other bits of code (albeit with some compiler-specific assumptions to determine where a function ends and to assume they know how one starts).

Comment: @Tommy "a pointer is a pointer is a pointer, including function pointers" -- when talking C, that's wrong. Function pointers are different in several ways: They're constructed and dereferenced implicitly (`f == &f`, `fp(x) == (*fp)(x)`), they don't have a size (`sizeof(fp)` is illegal), they aren't guaranteed to fit into a `intptr_t` or `void *`. It's perfectly possible that these are idiosyncrasies of the C standard and on these platforms there are no differences, but this would be a fact worth pointing out.

Comment: @delnan Functions don't have a size, but AFAIK function pointers certainly do. Do you have a source for this?

Answer (score 4):

ARM has two modes - legacy (AKA "ARM" proper) and Thumb. In ARM mode, instructions are aligned on 4 byte boundary, in Thumb - on 2 byte. The CPU uses the zeroth bit for calls that switch mode: to go from ARM to Thumb, you issue a branch-and-switch-mode command to an address with its rightmost bit set to 1.

The preferred mode for native userland code happens to be Thumb on two most popular ARM-based platforms (iOS and Android). Yet interworking with ARM has to be supported. So there are effectively no unused bits in the address.

Comment: It is even worse: The lowest bit is used to distinguish between the two modes! This means: Both of the bits are used!

Comment: B/BL commands in either mode ignore the lowest bit. Only BX/BLX use it for mode switch. So yes and no :) And in Thumb, the second lowest bit it a part of an address.

Answer (score 1):

On ARM the low bit has a special meaning: It switches between Thumb and traditional mode. In Thumb mode the instructions are 16-bit aligned so both bits are used.

On AMD64 and x86 depending on the optimization mode functions may be located at odd addresses. This means that the low two bits are always in use.

Answer (score -2):

There's no major modern platform that doesn't require its instructions to be at least 4-byte aligned, and I don't know of any C compiler which uses the low bytes for its own purposes. Blah blah blah about undefined behavior of operating on casted pointers in C, but you're safe.

EDIT: As pointed out below, for ARM Thumb, you only get one bit, and you need to make sure to clear it before you do the jump. For i386, some linkers won't do the alignment when optimization is disabled.

Comment: "no major modern platform that doesn't require its instructions to be at least 4-byte aligned" - Work in embedded world (Billions of processors per year) that certainly are not "at least 4-byte aligned".

Comment: It doesn't, that the point. I'm providing a counterexample to Sneftel's opening statement. One can argue that Intel is hardly modern :)

Comment: PowerPC VLE and ARM Thumb are 2-byte aligned only. ARM even uses the lowest bit of a function pointer to distinguish between Thumb and traditional mode.

Comment: Even i386 linkers align functions to 4-byte boundaries for performance reasons. Good point about the Thumb, though.

Comment: GNU C will align functions to a byte boundary only when using the "-Os" switch. I just tried a small program; there are functions with odd addresses!

Comment: Even if they do, that's an optimization, not a CPU requirement. If one's implementing a compiler, they can enforce pretty much any arbitrary alignment.